# How to override blob while doing server side copy using transferManager

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am facing an issue while using TransferManager to copy blobs from one container to another
with overwrite requirement.
I am force overwriting in the transfercontext below is the snippet.

```
             var sourceFile =
              this.sourceContainerManagement
              .GetCloudBlobClinet()
              .GetContainerReference(sourceContainer)
              .GetBlockBlobReference(source);

            var destinationFile =
                this.destinationContainerManagement
                .GetCloudBlobClinet()
                .GetContainerReference(destinationContainer)
                .GetBlockBlobReference(destination);

            var transferContext = new SingleTransferContext();

            // Force overwrite the destination without existence check.
            if (forceOverwrite)
            {
                transferContext.ShouldOverwriteCallbackAsync = TransferContext.ForceOverwrite;
            }

            await TransferManager.CopyAsync(
                sourceFile,
                destinationFile,
                clientSideCopy ? CopyMethod.SyncCopy : CopyMethod.ServiceSideSyncCopy,
                new CopyOptions(),
                transferContext);
```

With this client side copy( CopyMethod.SyncCopy)is successfully overwriting but server side copy(CopyMethod.ServiceSideSyncCopy) is failing with below exception.

> { "time": "2022-10-20 14:47:26.4432", "level": "ERROR", "logger":
> "DataStoreCopyWorkflow", "exception":
> "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferException: The transfer
> failed.\r\n ---> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Blob
> operation is not supported.\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1
> cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext,
> CancellationToken token)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.BlockBlobServiceSideSyncCopyController.CopyChunkAsync()
> in
> C:\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferControllers\ServiceSideSyncCopyControllers\BlockBlobServiceSideSyncCopyController.cs:line
> 209\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.ServiceSideSyncCopyController.DoWorkInternalAsync()
> in
> C:\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferControllers\ServiceSideSyncCopyControllers\ServiceSideSyncCopyController.cs:line
> 100\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferControllers.TransferControllerBase.DoWorkAsync()
> in
> C:\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferControllers\TransferControllerBase.cs:line
> 248\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferScheduler.ExecuteJobInternalAsync(TransferJob
> job, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> C:\azure-storage-net-data-movement\lib\TransferScheduler.cs:line
> 219\r\nRequest
> Information\r\nRequestID:ca460bcf-101e-005e-2464-e4740d000000\r\nRequestDate:Thu,
> 20 Oct 2022 14:47:26 GMT\r\nStatusMessage:Blob operation is not
> supported.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement;
namespace overiteblob
{
    class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string sourceStorageConnectionString = "<connection-string>";
            CloudStorageAccount sourceAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(sourceStorageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient sourceBlobClient = sourceAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer sourceBlobContainer = sourceBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("scores.json");

            string destStorageConnectionString = "<connection string>";
            CloudStorageAccount destAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(destStorageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient destBlobClient = destAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer destBlobContainer = destBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
            CloudBlockBlob destBlob = destBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blob.json");

            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
            SingleTransferContext transferContext = new SingleTransferContext();
            transferContext.ShouldOverwriteCallbackAsync = TransferContext.ForceOverwrite;

            var task = TransferManager.CopyAsync(
                sourceBlob, destBlob, CopyMethod.ServiceSideSyncCopy, null, transferContext, CancellationToken.None);
            task.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**
I tried the above code and successfully copied from one container to another container with overwrite using data movement library nugets.

[image]

**Reference:**
[TransferManager.CopyAsync Method (Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement) - Azure for .NET Developers | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.datamovement.transfermanager.copyasync?view=azure-dotnet)